# Como se dice " what's the use" en castellano?

Tags: gramática, modismos

> que es el uso, si tu compras una guitarra y tu no vas a tocarla?

What's the use of buying a guitar if you're not going to play it ?

Es la expresión " que es el uso" correcta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Colombia it states for:
    Para qué?

This is in a highly hesitating mood.

Answer (score 6):

“ What's the use” ===> "De qué sirve"

So:

```
What's the use of buying a guitar if you're not going to play it?
```

becomes:

```
¿De qué sirve comprar una guitarra si no la vas a tocar?
```

Answer (score 4):

In Spanish I'd ask literally: Why would you buy a guitar if you're not going to play it?

Which can be translated as:

¿Por qué comprarías una guitarra si no vas a tocarla (o utilizarla)?

Answer (score 3):

La expresión `qué es el uso` no es correcta.

Lo mas normal en Español sería utilizar algo como:

> ¿De qué te sirve comprar una guitarra si no vas a tocarla?

O:

> ¿Para qué compras una guitarra si no piensas tocarla?

Answer (score 3):

Adicionalmente a lo anteriormente respondido, también se puede traducir como:

- ¿Cuál es la utilidad de comprar una guitarra que no vas a usar?
- ¿Qué utilidad tiene comprar una guitarra que no vas a usar?

Answer (score 2):

`que es el uso` No es para nada correcta.

Una traducción de esa frase en sentido casi literal sería:

> ¿Cuál es el valor de uso de comprar una guitarra si no la vas a usar?

Pero `valor de uso` me recuerda más a las clases de Economía política y no es muy común.

Yo utilizaría:

> ¿Cuál es la idea de comprar una guitarra si no la vas a usar?
>
> ¿Cuál es la intención ...?
>
> ¿Cuál es el sentido ...?

**NOTE**

> si tú compras una guitarra y [tú] no vas a tocarla

El español no es como el inglés que siempre tienes que usar el pronombre, en el español este se omite en la segunda parte.